# PHP find text in self

Tags: php

```
if (strpos(file_get_contents($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']),'<html>')) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

I'm trying to check if the current page contains a string, and if so echo true. I've tried this however it doesn't work.

Comment: Make sure `file_get_contents($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']);` works by `echo`ing or `var_dump()`ing the contents. Your server configuration may not allow for `file_get_contents()` and you may need to use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php).

Comment: If "it doesn't work", at least tell us what happens when you try! :-)

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` contains [a completely different value than you seem to be expecting](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php):

> The IP address of the server under which the current script is executing.

To get a working link to the current page:

```
$currentUrl = $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ? 'https://' : 'http://';
$currentUrl .= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

However, this becomes a giant mess, if you're requesting your own page from that page's code you'll get a clusterf*ck of endless recursive retrievals which will eventually blow up your server. I would 'recommend' not downloading the page in which you are doing this.

Comment: Whoever downvoted: common courtesy requires you to explain why.